# CAS 6.5.7 - h2 and spring-security-core vulnerabilities

Tags: cas

We are upgrading the CAS version to 6.5.7 from 6.3.5. But found that 2 dependencies have critical vulnerabilities.

h2Version=1.4.197, this version reported vulnerabilities CVE-2021-23463, CVE-2022-23221 and CVE-2021-42392
springSecurityVersion=5.6.1, this version reported vulnerability CVE-2022-22978

We would like to know the CAS'mitigation plan for the above issues. Can we ask for a new version of CAS that packages the safe versions of h2 ( 2.1.210 or higher) and spring-security-core (5.6.4 or higher)? If so, when will the version be released?

It will be very helpful if we can have mitigation details for the above dependencies so we can plan our release. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> We would like to know the CAS'mitigation plan for the above issues.

Please read:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Sec-Vuln-Response.html

> Given the amount of effort involved in planning and releasing a security patch and disclosing the issue, communicating descriptions, intent, attack window and fixes, etc it is generally best to keep security releases reserved for issues that actually can be reproduced based on a concrete use case or those that truly and in practice affect the inner workings of the CAS software in a real way. If you could have such a use case at some point, please be sure to supply details and steps to reproduce issues. Supposed vulnerabilities that are picked up and reported by security scanners, static code analyzers and such affecting a third party library used by CAS generally do not qualify, unless there is solid evidence provided by the reporter to indicate a real, practical issue affecting CAS daily ops. Such warnings often appear superficial in the context of a CAS deployment. Usually, the best course of action would be to make the upgrades either locally to the installation script or switch to a more recent CAS version that might remove such warnings.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details on how CAS intends to upgrade dependencies. We are using the latest CAS v 6.5.7, which has reported the issues mentioned above. We shall revert if we can find re-produce the vulnerabilities.